# Jdbc Acknowledgment (ACK) in Mule for outbound endpoint

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

I am using jbdc acknowledgement process for my jdbc inbound endpoint it works well. Is it possible to use the same process for my jdbc outbound endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JDBC Acknowledgement process for JDBC outbound endpoint ... For example here in the flow the JDBC outbound endpoint is calling **RetrieveQuery** which does a simple Select operation and then the .ack query is automatically called which insert Data into DB :-

```
 <jdbc-ee:connector name="Database_Global" dataSource-ref="DB_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database">

<jdbc-ee:query key="RetrieveQuery.ack" value="INSERT INTO getData(ID,NAME,AGE,DESIGNATION)VALUES(2,'rrrrrr',44,'tttttt')"/>
<jdbc-ee:query key="RetrieveQuery" value="Select * from getData"/>

</jdbc-ee:connector>

<flow name="Flow1" doc:name="Flow1">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="7777" path="aa" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="RetrieveQuery" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="Database_Global" doc:name="Database (JDBC)"/>
<json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
<logger message=" payload #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Thanks Anirban. Actually I used payload in my ack query there I went wrong. Its working fine thanks for your help.